# Is there a way of getting the response.content for a post request in Django testing?

Tags: django

This article - https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-use-django-test-client-to-test-views/ - suggests that we can access response.content to get the content of the response after sending a post request.  However I've just created a dead simple project and app to test this but I just get an empty byte string.  What am I missing?

Models -

```
class Note(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Views -

```
class CreateNote(CreateView):
    model = Note
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("index")

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")
```

Tests -

```
class NoteTest(TestCase):

    def test_createNote(self):
        response = self.client.post('/notes/create', {'text': 'hello world!'})
        print(response.content) # just returns b''
```

The article is wrong.  Or the article does not involve a redirect.  So the answer is to test like this.

```
    def test_createNote(self):
        response = self.client.post('/notes/create', {'text': 'hello world!'}, follow=True)
        print(response.content)
```

Comment: A succesful POST request, will normally result in a redirect, hence it is makes sense that the content is empty.

Comment: Well I did think that because I'm always testing for a status code of 302 but the article made me think otherwise.  So the article is wrong in other words.  Thought this might be the case.  How would you check the content of the redirect within the same test?  Is there a follow option for the post test method?

Comment: Just found out there is.  Will update the question with the answer.